# Searching in Sqlite Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, search

i need to build an iPhone app that's search in Sqlite Database by using search bar and display the result in UITableView , could any one give me tutorial or source code to trace them , Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searching using SQL query, refer the LIKE operator: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

The query normally comes out to be something like this:

```
NSString *nsquery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM RECIPE WHERE RECIPENAME LIKE '%@'", someRecipeName];
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite: here is tutorial for quick learning

[http:// www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_(Xcode_4)](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)

if you want exact string Match

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
               @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"", 
               name.text];
```

if you want to match string as substring

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString initWithFormat:@"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE '%@'",someName];
```

Here is more example of how to use Like

/* Returns all users whose name starts with "d" */

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE 'd%'
```

/* Returns all users whose name contains "dav" */

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE '%dav%'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: That link goes to an empty page.

Comment: Thanks, now its corrected, working now...